# Why is my text align not working?

Tags: html, css

Here is the code.
The text align wont work.

```
html {
    position: fixed;
    top: -50px;
    background-color: #c4f3ff;
}

div {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
}
h1 {
    font-family: monospace;
    line-height: normal;
    color: #fffb29;
    font-size: 50px;
    position: fixed;
    top: -20px;
}
```

Here is a screen shot of the result
[image]

Comment: Is the code so long that you can't post it?

Comment: can you post this on jsfiddle?

Comment: @AVI He is required to post an example of the code that shows the problem here, not a jsfiddle or a Drive either.

Comment: As you've set HTML to `position:fixed` - 100% width is not calculated as 100% of viewport - try `width: 100vw;` for the div's or for HTML - either way will work

Comment: You have to add the BODY tag to your html maybe?

Comment: Why not include both the CSS and the HTML in a runnable snippet instead of an image that just says "enter image description here"

Answer (score 2):

You mean the yellow text need to be align to center/right or somewhere?
If so, you just use:

```
h1{
   width:100%;
   text-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your css file you marked your html (??) and all your divs with

```
position: fixed;
```

Position fixed elements will need a width as well. add

```
width: 100%;
```

or

```
width: 100vw;
```

So it can center your text.